# Get Div ID and add it to a session Varaible

Tags: php, mysql, variables

I have managed to dynamically assign a unique id to a button which is dependent on the users returned from the mysql query.The code run though and prints a profile image, username and a button which is assigned a value based on the userID pulled from the database.

However, I am struggling to get the id of the button selected and add it as a session variable, so that sub pages can be filtered based on the button id pulled.

When pressing on the View Profile button, I want the button id which has been assigned to that to be stored as session variable so that the profileTemplate page is then filtered by that id pulled.

Button Code

```
echo "<div align=\"center\"><button href=\"profileTemplate.php\" id=" . $info['userID'] . " class=\"btn btn-success btn-md\" type=\"submit\">View Profile</button></div>\n";
```

Comment: your `<button>` has no `name`, so there's nothing to submit with the rest of the form.

Comment: `id`s aren't submitted with form posts.  `name`s are submitted as the keys to identify the values of any given form element.  So at the very least you need a `name` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving id to the href, so you can receive it with $_GET['id']

```
echo "<div align=\"center\"><button href=\"profileTemplate.php?id={$info['userID']}\" class=\"btn btn-success btn-md\" type=\"submit\">View Profile</button></div>\n";
```

Comment: How could I then assign the userID into the where clause of the profileTemplate page?

Comment: $sql = "select * from profile where profile_id = '{$_GET['id']}'";